# Mean and variance dimension mismatch

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, mean, variance

I need to calculate the mean and the variance of training set for anomaly detection but keep getting dimension mismatch error.

```
mean_train = 1/(num_train )* sum(Xtrain);
var_train =  1/(num_train )* sum(Xtrain - mean_train).^2;
```

Comment: try watching the size of variables and debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all show all data, because we can't reproduce your mistake.
I suggest, you take this error because of this:
`mean_train` or `num_train` is a vector and then we can't simply multiply it or minus it with `Xtrain`.

But the answer for you:
just use build-in Matlab functions [mean](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mean.html?refresh=true) and [var](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/var.html?searchHighlight=var). This let you use it in this way:

```
mean(Xtrain)
```

avoiding using secondary variables like `num_train`.

---

I checked your code and found mistake:
`Xtrain` is an 100x2 array. And using `sum` on it returns 1x2 array! You can read about this in help:

> If A is a matrix, then sum(A) returns a row vector containing the sum
>   of each column.

So your next action:

```
mean_train = 1/(num_train )* sum(Xtrain);
```

returns 1x2 array and matlab can't make this: `Xtrain - mean_train`.

Answer is easy:
use `sum` twice like this: `sum(sum(Xtrain))`

Comment: The full code can be found here:
http://cornelis.website/code/Anomaly.m

And a test for the code can be found here:
http://cornelis.website/code/test.m

Comment: @JeandeToit I checked your code and found mistake. Look my edited answer!